# how to bypass Sucuri Website Firewall in webscraping?

Tags: web-scraping

im trying to scrape one website that has  Sucuri WebSite Firewall. Is there any way to bypass this Firewall? I have tried with using VPN, but that doesnt work and i still have Access Denied

Answer (score 0):

Use a header before the URL

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.google.com/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
}

response = requests.get('your url', headers=headers)
```